# Working with a sleeping CPU?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance

Reading about how android devices work, It says the CPU quickly goes to sleep as soon as the device is left idle for timeout period. However certain applications might keep the CPU awake using wakelocks and thus give a huge impact on battery backup.

My question is if you do not use wake locks for CPU then the CPU would surely go to sleep and a a sleeping CPU means one that isn't processing anything, then in such a state how will the background services and other things keep working?

How will an application do things such a listening on network socket with a  sleeping CPU ?

Or does a sleeping CPU is not completely inactive when sleeping?

I am talking in terms of application layer not the hardware layer where it has interrupts to wake up etc.

Comment: any service running in the background like "file download service" etc need to acquire a wake lock

Comment: @pskink what about less active work like listening for socket or broadcasts  , all those require wakelock as well? In that case No Device will ever be able to sleep if it has a assortment of apps like mail,IMs etc

Comment: see "Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)"

Answer (score 0):

On most CPUs, the kernel can decrease the CPU clock rate, turn off some CPU cores, and maybe even power down some caches, all to reduce power consumption. This is what happens when your Android device goes to sleep, but the exact changes are different from one phone to another. The CPU is still running, just more slowly, and drawing less power. If the phone uses ARM's big.LITTLE system per say, it might even be a completely different CPU core that runs in sleep mode: a slower one tuned for low power consumption.

For more details please read:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/69693/how-do-timers-and-alarms-function-while-the-device-is-sleeping